# Filtering for "DEBUG" in less shows no results in some machines. Why?

Tags: bash, less

Given

```
x@x:~$ echo -e "DEBUG\nDEBAG" | less
```

When attempting to filter the output in less with `&DEBUG`, no results are shown (on my work server). But then trying this in my home computer (Ubuntu 16) works fine. What may be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: I mean pressing & and then typing "DEBUG" (without double quotes).

Comment: @l0b0, `&` tells `less` to filter the shown lines to those matching a pattern

Comment: Is your work server a Windows machine?

Comment: No, it's a Linux machine. I'll have to work which distro they're running, "uname -a" isn't returning anything useful.

Comment: First thing to do if the same program on different machines behave differently is to check the version. I don't believe this will lead anywhere since `&` is not exactly a bleeding edge feature. But it also doesn't hurt, so what does `less --version` give?

Comment: Less 424 at work

Comment: That is pretty old, though...

Comment: Anyway, is there some way of installing that same version at home to give it a try?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. You can try it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using less 424. I installed [less 418](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/) (I couldn't find less 424), and indeed, this feature is not available in this version. less 418 is from 2008!

The only thing you can do is to install it yourself, or to convince your system administrator that a newer version of less is not a threat to the stability of their servers. Your system administrator might still be reluctant to install a newer version of less, since probably the version of less is installed that comes with the package manager.

On my server I use Scientific Linux 6.8, and here less 436 is installed, which is also pretty old, but the `&` operator works.